# how to remove the "undefined text" from my webpage

Tags: javascript, html, function, error-handling

I'm building a quiz page and everything is working fine except for a text that appears on the page which reads "undefined". It should be an error somewhere on the Javascript.
I've tried everything I can think of

## **The HTML**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>quiz</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="game">
                <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this question</h2>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">choice 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">choice 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">choice 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">choice 4</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="5">choice 5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

## **The JavaScript:**

```
const question = document.getElementById("question");
const choices = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("choice-text"));

let currentQuestion = {};
let acceptingAnswers = false;
let score = 0;
let questionCounter = 0;
let availableQuestions = [];


let questions = [
    {
      question: "Commonly used data types DO NOT include:",
      choice1: "1. strings",
      choice2: "2. booleans",
      choice3: "3. alerts",
      choice4: "4. numbers",
      answer: 3
    },
    {
      question: "Arrays in JavaScript can be used to store ______.", 
        choice1: "1. numbers and strings",
        choice2: "2. other arrays",
        choice3: "3. booleans",
        choice4: "4. all of the above",
      
      answer: 4
    },
    {
      question: "String values must be enclosed within _____ when being assigned to variables.",
      choice1: "1. commas",
      choice2:  "2. curly brackets",
      choice3: "3. quotes",
      choice4: "4. parentheses",
      answer: 3,
    },
    {
      question: "A very useful tool used during development and debugging for printing content to the debugger is:",
        choice1: "1. JavaScript",
        choice2: "2. terminal/bash",
        choice3: "3. for loops",
        choice4: "4. console.log",
      answer: 4
    },
    {
      question:
        "Which of the following is a statement that can be used to terminate a loop, switch or label statement?",
      choice1: "1. break",
      choice2: "2. stop", 
      choice3: "3. halt",
      choice4: "4. exit",
      answer: 1
    },
  ];

const CORRECT_BONUS = 10;
const MAX_QUESTIONS = 5;

startGame = () => {
    questionCounter = 0;
    score = 0;
    availableQuestions = [...questions];
    console.log(availableQuestions);
    getNewQuestion();

};
getNewQuestion = () => {
    if (availableQuestions.length === 0 || questionCounter >= MAX_QUESTIONS){
        //go to end page
        return window.location.assign('/finished.html');
    }
    questionCounter++;
    const questionIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * availableQuestions.length);
    currentQuestion = availableQuestions[questionIndex];
    question.innerText = currentQuestion.question;

    choices.forEach( choice =>{
        const number = choice.dataset['number'];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
    })

    availableQuestions.splice(questionIndex, 1);

    acceptingAnswers = true;
};

choices.forEach( choice => {
    choice.addEventListener('click', e => {
     if(!acceptingAnswers) return;

     acceptingAnswers = false;
     const selectedChoice = e.target;
     const selectedAnswer = selectedChoice.dataset['number'];
     getNewQuestion();
    })

})

startGame();
```

The page should display without any undefined text. Everything else works fine, I just need help with that undefined error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behavious is because you have only 4 options in each question and you are rendering 5 choices

```
choices.forEach( choice =>{
        const number = choice.dataset['number'];
        choice.innerText = currentQuestion['choice' + number];
    })
```

At this phase, you are changing the text of options and as you have 5 choices in html and only 4 option in question, it renders as undefined,

The solution is to remove 5th choise from the html

```
<div class="container">
            <div id="game">
                <h2 id="question">What is the answer to this question</h2>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="1">choice 1</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="2">choice 2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="3">choice 3</p>
                </div>
                <div class="choice-container">
                    <p class="choice-text" data-number="4">choice 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```